# KineticJS Canvas Save to Computer button

Tags: javascript, html, image, kineticjs

I'm trying to add a save button that is going to be on the page but not in the canvas. Every online example I try I can't seem to get the canvas to save right. I'd like to basically make it so they click the save button and it either automatically downloads as an image or opens the save to my computer window for them to rename, move, and save, etc. www.jsfiddle.net/dsj00qoy/16/

```
    <button id="save">Save as image</button>
  <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>       <script src="http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/Blob.js"></script>
          <script src="http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/canvas-toBlob.js"></script>
          <script src="http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://53d4e26fadb6e09777fddd385fe78ac4b63826d5.googledrive.com/host/0B71KNg66uHaYR014NlB4b0c0ZWc/btq1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Edited to add some of the coding from my page. Above this coding is the canvas itself and some other html. The last line of js from google drive is my js file for the canvas itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Good News:**

The new `canvas.toBlob` method allows you to convert a canvas to a blob and then you can use `saveAs` to let the user download that blob as an image to their local drive.

**The Bad News:**

Most browsers have not yet implemented `.toBlob` and `saveAs`.

**The Workaround:**

Eli Grey has written a great shim to allow you to use toBlob+saveAs in existing browsers:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Here's an example using Eli Grey's shim.

KineticJS is really a set (stage) of canvases (layers). For KineticJS you have these additional steps to create 1 canvas containing all KineticJS layers.

- Create an imageURL from the stage (see stage.toDataURL).
- Create an image from the imageURL.
- Create an in-memory canvas.
- DrawImage your created image onto the in-memory canvas.
- Use the in-memory canvas plus Eli Grey's shim to let the user push a button and save the stage to their local drive as an image.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image()
img.onload=function(){
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.fillRect(100,100,50,30);
}
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png";


$("#save").click(function(){
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){ saveAs(blob,"temp4.png"); });
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="save">Save</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>


<script>
  /* FileSaver.js
             * A saveAs() FileSaver implementation.
             * 2014-08-29
             *
             * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
             * License: X11/MIT
             *   See https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
             */

  /*global self */
  /*jslint bitwise: true, indent: 4, laxbreak: true, laxcomma: true, smarttabs: true, plusplus: true */

  /*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js */

  var saveAs = saveAs
  // IE 10+ (native saveAs)
  || (typeof navigator !== "undefined" &&
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob && navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob.bind(navigator))
  // Everyone else
  || (function(view) {
    "use strict";
    // IE <10 is explicitly unsupported
    if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" &&
        /MSIE [1-9]\./.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      return;
    }
    var
    doc = view.document
    // only get URL when necessary in case Blob.js hasn't overridden it yet
    , get_URL = function() {
      return view.URL || view.webkitURL || view;
    }
    , save_link = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a")
    , can_use_save_link = "download" in save_link
    , click = function(node) {
      var event = doc.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      event.initMouseEvent(
        "click", true, false, view, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , false, false, false, false, 0, null
      );
      node.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    , webkit_req_fs = view.webkitRequestFileSystem
    , req_fs = view.requestFileSystem || webkit_req_fs || view.mozRequestFileSystem
    , throw_outside = function(ex) {
      (view.setImmediate || view.setTimeout)(function() {
        throw ex;
      }, 0);
    }
    , force_saveable_type = "application/octet-stream"
    , fs_min_size = 0
    // See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375297#c7 for
    // the reasoning behind the timeout and revocation flow
    , arbitrary_revoke_timeout = 10
    , revoke = function(file) {
      var revoker = function() {
        if (typeof file === "string") { // file is an object URL
          get_URL().revokeObjectURL(file);
        } else { // file is a File
          file.remove();
        }
      };
      if (view.chrome) {
        revoker();
      } else {
        setTimeout(revoker, arbitrary_revoke_timeout);
      }
    }
    , dispatch = function(filesaver, event_types, event) {
      event_types = [].concat(event_types);
      var i = event_types.length;
      while (i--) {
        var listener = filesaver["on" + event_types[i]];
        if (typeof listener === "function") {
          try {
            listener.call(filesaver, event || filesaver);
          } catch (ex) {
            throw_outside(ex);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    , FileSaver = function(blob, name) {
      // First try a.download, then web filesystem, then object URLs
      var
      filesaver = this
      , type = blob.type
      , blob_changed = false
      , object_url
      , target_view
      , dispatch_all = function() {
        dispatch(filesaver, "writestart progress write writeend".split(" "));
      }
      // on any filesys errors revert to saving with object URLs
      , fs_error = function() {
        // don't create more object URLs than needed
        if (blob_changed || !object_url) {
          object_url = get_URL().createObjectURL(blob);
        }
        if (target_view) {
          target_view.location.href = object_url;
        } else {
          var new_tab = view.open(object_url, "_blank");
          if (new_tab == undefined && typeof safari !== "undefined") {
            //Apple do not allow window.open, see http://bit.ly/1kZffRI
            view.location.href = object_url
          }
        }
        filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
        dispatch_all();
        revoke(object_url);
      }
      , abortable = function(func) {
        return function() {
          if (filesaver.readyState !== filesaver.DONE) {
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
          }
        };
      }
      , create_if_not_found = {create: true, exclusive: false}
      , slice
      ;
      filesaver.readyState = filesaver.INIT;
      if (!name) {
        name = "download";
      }
      if (can_use_save_link) {
        object_url = get_URL().createObjectURL(blob);
        save_link.href = object_url;
        save_link.download = name;
        click(save_link);
        filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
        dispatch_all();
        revoke(object_url);
        return;
      }
      // Object and web filesystem URLs have a problem saving in Google Chrome when
      // viewed in a tab, so I force save with application/octet-stream
      // http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91158
      // Update: Google errantly closed 91158, I submitted it again:
      // https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389642
      if (view.chrome && type && type !== force_saveable_type) {
        slice = blob.slice || blob.webkitSlice;
        blob = slice.call(blob, 0, blob.size, force_saveable_type);
        blob_changed = true;
      }
      // Since I can't be sure that the guessed media type will trigger a download
      // in WebKit, I append .download to the filename.
      // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65440
      if (webkit_req_fs && name !== "download") {
        name += ".download";
      }
      if (type === force_saveable_type || webkit_req_fs) {
        target_view = view;
      }
      if (!req_fs) {
        fs_error();
        return;
      }
      fs_min_size += blob.size;
      req_fs(view.TEMPORARY, fs_min_size, abortable(function(fs) {
        fs.root.getDirectory("saved", create_if_not_found, abortable(function(dir) {
          var save = function() {
            dir.getFile(name, create_if_not_found, abortable(function(file) {
              file.createWriter(abortable(function(writer) {
                writer.onwriteend = function(event) {
                  target_view.location.href = file.toURL();
                  filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
                  dispatch(filesaver, "writeend", event);
                  revoke(file);
                };
                writer.onerror = function() {
                  var error = writer.error;
                  if (error.code !== error.ABORT_ERR) {
                    fs_error();
                  }
                };
                "writestart progress write abort".split(" ").forEach(function(event) {
                  writer["on" + event] = filesaver["on" + event];
                });
                writer.write(blob);
                filesaver.abort = function() {
                  writer.abort();
                  filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
                };
                filesaver.readyState = filesaver.WRITING;
              }), fs_error);
            }), fs_error);
          };
          dir.getFile(name, {create: false}, abortable(function(file) {
            // delete file if it already exists
            file.remove();
            save();
          }), abortable(function(ex) {
            if (ex.code === ex.NOT_FOUND_ERR) {
              save();
            } else {
              fs_error();
            }
          }));
        }), fs_error);
      }), fs_error);
    }
    , FS_proto = FileSaver.prototype
    , saveAs = function(blob, name) {
      return new FileSaver(blob, name);
    }
    ;
    FS_proto.abort = function() {
      var filesaver = this;
      filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
      dispatch(filesaver, "abort");
    };
    FS_proto.readyState = FS_proto.INIT = 0;
    FS_proto.WRITING = 1;
    FS_proto.DONE = 2;

    FS_proto.error =
      FS_proto.onwritestart =
      FS_proto.onprogress =
      FS_proto.onwrite =
      FS_proto.onabort =
      FS_proto.onerror =
      FS_proto.onwriteend =
      null;

    return saveAs;
  }(
    typeof self !== "undefined" && self
    || typeof window !== "undefined" && window
    || this.content
  ));
  // `self` is undefined in Firefox for Android content script context
  // while `this` is nsIContentFrameMessageManager
  // with an attribute `content` that corresponds to the window

  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
    module.exports = saveAs;
  } else if ((typeof define !== "undefined" && define !== null) && (define.amd != null)) {
    define([], function() {
      return saveAs;
    });
  }
</script>

<script>
  /* canvas-toBlob.js
             * A canvas.toBlob() implementation.
             * 2013-12-27
             * 
             * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com and Devin Samarin, https://github.com/eboyjr
             * License: X11/MIT
             *   See https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
             */

  /*global self */
  /*jslint bitwise: true, regexp: true, confusion: true, es5: true, vars: true, white: true,
              plusplus: true */

  /*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/canvas-toBlob.js/blob/master/canvas-toBlob.js */

  (function(view) {
    "use strict";
    var
    Uint8Array = view.Uint8Array
    , HTMLCanvasElement = view.HTMLCanvasElement
    , canvas_proto = HTMLCanvasElement && HTMLCanvasElement.prototype
    , is_base64_regex = /\s*;\s*base64\s*(?:;|$)/i
    , to_data_url = "toDataURL"
    , base64_ranks
    , decode_base64 = function(base64) {
      var
      len = base64.length
      , buffer = new Uint8Array(len / 4 * 3 | 0)
      , i = 0
      , outptr = 0
      , last = [0, 0]
      , state = 0
      , save = 0
      , rank
      , code
      , undef
      ;
      while (len--) {
        code = base64.charCodeAt(i++);
        rank = base64_ranks[code-43];
        if (rank !== 255 && rank !== undef) {
          last[1] = last[0];
          last[0] = code;
          save = (save << 6) | rank;
          state++;
          if (state === 4) {
            buffer[outptr++] = save >>> 16;
            if (last[1] !== 61 /* padding character */) {
              buffer[outptr++] = save >>> 8;
            }
            if (last[0] !== 61 /* padding character */) {
              buffer[outptr++] = save;
            }
            state = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      // 2/3 chance there's going to be some null bytes at the end, but that
      // doesn't really matter with most image formats.
      // If it somehow matters for you, truncate the buffer up outptr.
      return buffer;
    }
    ;
    if (Uint8Array) {
      base64_ranks = new Uint8Array([
        62, -1, -1, -1, 63, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, -1
        , -1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9
        , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
        , -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
        , 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
      ]);
    }
    if (HTMLCanvasElement && !canvas_proto.toBlob) {
      canvas_proto.toBlob = function(callback, type /*, ...args*/) {
        if (!type) {
          type = "image/png";
        } if (this.mozGetAsFile) {
          callback(this.mozGetAsFile("canvas", type));
          return;
        } if (this.msToBlob && /^\s*image\/png\s*(?:$|;)/i.test(type)) {
          callback(this.msToBlob());
          return;
        }

        var
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
        , dataURI = this[to_data_url].apply(this, args)
        , header_end = dataURI.indexOf(",")
        , data = dataURI.substring(header_end + 1)
        , is_base64 = is_base64_regex.test(dataURI.substring(0, header_end))
        , blob
        ;
        if (Blob.fake) {
          // no reason to decode a data: URI that's just going to become a data URI again
          blob = new Blob
          if (is_base64) {
            blob.encoding = "base64";
          } else {
            blob.encoding = "URI";
          }
          blob.data = data;
          blob.size = data.length;
        } else if (Uint8Array) {
          if (is_base64) {
            blob = new Blob([decode_base64(data)], {type: type});
          } else {
            blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(data)], {type: type});
          }
        }
        callback(blob);
      };

      if (canvas_proto.toDataURLHD) {
        canvas_proto.toBlobHD = function() {
          to_data_url = "toDataURLHD";
          var blob = this.toBlob();
          to_data_url = "toDataURL";
          return blob;
        }
      } else {
        canvas_proto.toBlobHD = canvas_proto.toBlob;
      }
    }
  }(typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content || this));


</script>
```

**[ About scripts -- just my opinion ]**

Ah, yes...script organization.  Like chefs, everyone seems to vary their organizing methods to suit their own tastes.  Personally, I do it this way. (1) Always use CDN's for 3rd party software like jQuery.  That's because jQuery (and other 3rd party stuff) is probably already cached on the user's device. If the browser sees it needs jQuery and it already has it cached then it will use the cached version and doesn't even download a duplicate jQuery. Caching is done based on the URL so use a well known CDN if possible. (2a) If the scripts total <10K then I put them in a single scripts.js file and include it on the page with a script tag. (2b) If the  scripts total >10K then I minify them and again include the minified script.js on the page with a script tag. Back on my development computers, I keep a copy of both the minified and unminified script file in case I need to do maintenance on the code. More thoughts: For sites that use heavy scripts that are common to many pages, I minify those scripts into a separate commonScripts.js. For heavy page-specific scripts I minify those scripts into a separate script file that's included on just the needed pages. Anyway, these are not laws--just how I organize scripts. Cheers!

Comment: So I have a .js file that has all the canvas stuff which I'm using as a source on my html page. Do I need to put this code in with that js or can I just place it in the page with the rest of my code like so... I put my main code right now in the edit above, the container itself is above all this.

Comment: My opinion about handling scripts was too long for a comment so I've added a bit to the end of my answer. Cheers!

Comment: This still doesn't seem to want to work, would using images hosted on another site have something to do with it? I saw somewhere that if you have pictures from another site it breaks it or something? I'm using chrome and when I right click the canvas i can save it and it shows everything, but I want to get rid of having to do that so they can just click a button and it saves instead. I also haven't tested if the right click and saving works in IE or mozilla yet so I want to make sure whatever I use will be cross browser.

Comment: After testing on IE and mozilla, the right click save image worked on mozilla but not on IE.

Comment: Ugh I figured out my issue... It's because I'm using images from other sites. I uploaded most the images to photobucket and linked them. Using this it works until I add those images then it no longer works. Is there some way around this??  
 `saver.on('click', function () {
     
        stage.toDataURL({
          callback: function(dataUrl) {
          
            window.open(dataUrl);
          }
        });
      }, false);`

Comment: If you load images from another domain, you've violated cross-site resource sharing (CORS) security restrictions.  When you do this, your canvas is marked "tainted" and you cannot do .toDataURL.  To avoid CORS violations you can host the images on your own web server and send appropriate headers when serving the images. Here's more info: http://enable-cors.org/  CORS Security exists for very valid reasons (you wouldn't want someone to use canvas to steal an image of your bank login screen). Browsers are working on allowing coders easier X-Site sharing, but for now you must follow the rules.